Prove $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_\limits{0}^\pi\max_\limits{1\le k\le n}|\sin(kx)|\frac{dx}{x}}{\ln{n}}=1$ and one more
Please help me proving the following:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_\limits{0}^\pi\max_\limits{1\le k\le n}|\sin(kx)|\frac{dx}{x}}{\ln{n}}=1$$
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_\limits{0}^\pi\max_\limits{2\le k\le n}|\frac{\sin(kx)}{\ln k}|\frac{dx}{x}}{\ln\ln{n}}=1$$
Speaking about the first one, I guess that $\int\frac{|sin(kx)|}{x}$ with large $k$ looks like $\int\frac{1}{x}$ (visually in geogebra). But I'm not sure if it's true and how to prove it.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
